# OpenCV - find curve line in captcha image

Tags: opencv

The captcha have same noise line.
[image]
It will run through the words.

These are captcha images for example:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

My idea is to find the noise line start and end points in captcha.
Then use loop through two image to find the line edges.
Is there any other method in OpenCV to do this?
Or another way to find out these noise lines?

Comment: Use thresholding technique to find noisy line and  then you can use template matching to suppress line in another images.

Comment: Thank your key word.I will study how to use it.